# Can't Load Google Map with GMapPanel - EXTJS 4

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, extjs, extjs4

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../ux');
Ext.require([
    'Ext.tree.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.window.MessageBox',
    'Ext.window.*',
    'Ext.ux.GMapPanel'
]);

var map = new Ext.ux.GMapPanel({
            xtype: 'gmappanel',
            region: 'center',
            id:  'mygooglemap',
            zoomLevel: 3,
            gmapType: 'map',
            setCenter: {
                'lat': 37.4419,
                'lng': -122.1419
            }
        });

    var layout = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            //renderTo: 'layout',
            width: window.innerWidth,
            height: window.innerHeight,
            //title: 'Border Layout', //no title will be blank
            layout: 'border',
            items: [{
                title: 'Message List',
                region: 'south',     // position for region
                xtype: 'panel',
                height: 100,
                split: true,         // enable resizing
                collapsible: true,
                margins: '0 5 5 5',
                collapsed: true
            },tree,map],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody() //get the body and display Layout at there
        });
```

### Question

all load successful, treepanel with name tree also load sucess,just the map GMapPanel can't show the google map,why?please help me,thanks. i have no idea

UPDATE
this the screenshot i have taken, the page should load google map,but is blank
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add marker object in side setCenter while creating map.

Modify your map code as below

```
var map = new Ext.ux.GMapPanel({
        xtype: 'gmappanel',
        region: 'center',
        id:  'mygooglemap',
        zoomLevel: 3,
        gmapType: 'map',
        mapConfOpts:['enableScrollWheelZoom','enableDoubleClickZoom','enableDragging'],
        mapControls: ['GSmallMapControl','GMapTypeControl','NonExistantControl'],   
        setCenter: {
            'lat': 37.4419,
            'lng': -122.1419,
            marker:{ title: 'Palo Alto'}
        }
    });
```

Comment: I edited my answer. You need to add mapConfOpts and mapControls too. These are basic config options you need to use at the time of gmap/gmappanel creation. Please go through them from docs.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>
```

on your index.html, if you'have done it yet, it will be helpful if you use debug browser tool to find if there are some errors that you didn't post